# Sending UDP packets across internet works only half

Tags: python, networking, video, stream, udp

I'am trying to send UDP packets with images to my friend who is behind his NAT. He forwarded his receiving port but the packets don't arrive using our python code. But nevertheless, when using test code the packet does arrive and the tuple containing IPaddr and PORT are the same.

NOTE: not a single exception was triggered, it simply gets stuck in the `recvfrom` because there is nothing to read

This is the sample code that I used to test if the packets arrive and it worked:

```py
import socket

IPADDR = '88.1.231.55'
PORTNUM = 8043

PACKETDATA = 'TEEEESSTT'.encode('ascii')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

s.sendto(PACKETDATA, (IPADDR, PORTNUM))

s.close()
```

Init of the UDP class:

```py
def __init__ (self, ip_dest, port_dest, port_src, tcp):
        self.TCP = tcp
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.dest = (str(ip_dest), int(port_dest))
        self.socket.bind(('', port_src))

        self.receiveVideoThread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_video)
        self.receiveVideoThread.setDaemon(True)
        self.receiveVideoThread.start()
        ...........
```

Send the image:

```py
def send_video(self, frame):
        if not self.TCP.pauseCall or not self.TCP.endCall:
            try:
                header = "{}#{}#{}#{}#".format(self.counter, time.time(), '640x480', self.fps).encode("utf-8")
                ratio = self.get_compress_ratio(self.fps_friend)
                frame = self.rescale_by_height(frame, 320)
                self.frame_sent = frame
                frame_compressed = self.compress(frame, 1)
                self.socket.sendto(header +  frame_compressed, self.dest)
                self.counter += 1
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return
```

And recieve:

```py
def receive_video(self):
        while not self.TCP.endCall or not self.TCP.pauseCall:
            try:
                data, _ = self.socket.recvfrom(200)
                datagram = data.split(b'#', 4)
                self.fps_friend = datagram[3]
                ........
```

When we use our code the packets show up on Wireshark but never arrive. When using the sample code the packet does arrive.

Could it be something related to the size of the packets? I've tried compressing the images at the maximum so now the size of an entire UDP packet is ~5KB

Comment: There's a lack of information here, in your code, we dont see how you actually build the sockets, wich could be the issue

Comment: The creation and the send function are the same as the sample code, but I'vs added the init function as well. On local network works fine. When looked at the packets on wireshark, the 'TEEST' one arrived with an index stream = 1 but our image packets have bigger index stream, between 100 and 300. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Usually stream flows indexes are relevant for TCP flows, tho Wireshark also increments it for UDP. It's not that shocking having a large flow index here since you are sending it across wan (dns requests stuff like that). Have you tried to just send data with netcat to you client to see if there's no issue with the port forwarding part ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to send data with netcat and hping3 and all work perfectly. And we also use a TCP connection to control the quality of the images and that as well works without any problem.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code snippets. Try to simplify by sending a very small packet, e.g. bytearray(100), remove compress function etc...